# A polynomial inequality

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Given $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n \ge 0, \alpha \ge 1$, show that

$\sum_{i}\alpha x_i(\sum_{j \le i}{x_j})^{\alpha-1} \ge (\sum_{i}x_i)^\alpha$

We're pretty sure the inequality holds for the given precondition. It can be validated using a small piece of matlab code. Now we post it for rigorous proof. Its continuous version is easy:

$\int^{n}\alpha x(\tau)(\int^{\tau}{x(t)}dt)^{\alpha-1}d\tau= (\int^{n}x(t)dt)^\alpha$

When writing down the proof, there are more details to be finalized, so we're stuck for a rigorous proof. Hope there's anyone who can help or point us to some resource.

Comment: Here's a sketch:
   * associate continuous $x(t)$ with $x_i$
   * construct an s(t) being integral of $x(t)$ and equal to or less than sum of $x_i$

Intuitively, it should work in this way but the construction seems not trivial. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $s_i = \sum_{j \leq i} x_j$, just write
$$ \sum_{i \leq n} \alpha x_i s_i^{\alpha-1} = \sum_{i \leq n} \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} \alpha s_i^{\alpha-1} dt \geq \sum_{i \leq n} \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} \alpha t^{\alpha-1} dt = \int_{0}^{s_n} \alpha t^{\alpha-1} dt = s_n^{\alpha}
$$

Comment: thanks very much. That's accurate now!! What a dull head I get.. I was all stucking thinking how to construct a continuous x(t)... 